# Remove unused third-party tab in github

Tags: github

I wanted to try out a third party application for github called ZenHub, I do not want to use it anymore. In github through the browser I have revoked the third-party access, under `Settings > Application > Authorized OAuth apps`, but I can still see it as aa tab in my repositories, and I am unable to remove it.

If I click the "ZenHub" tab, I am redirected to a page to re-authorize the application again.

I have added a picture to explain my issue, I would like to remove the "ZenHub" tab.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try removing it from your Chrome extensions.

Comment: Removing it from Chrome extensions worked for me - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove custom tabs by clicking the `Settings` tab on your repo, then the `Custom tabs` section and clicking the `Remove` button on the tab you'd like to delete.

[image: dialog showing how to remove a custom tab in GitHub]

Comment: Hmm, I do not have the "Custom tabs" section at all. But I did find it under a section I had called "Webhooks". Interestingely enough, removing the ZenHub "hook" removed the ZenHub tab from that repository only, and not my other repositories. And if I go into "Webhooks" setting in my other repositories, it is now empty ... very confusing!

Comment: Good to know! That is very confusing :-/